# IBus/settings keyboard layout interference in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, keyboard-layout, ibus

I'm using KDE+Ubuntu and for switching keyboard layout from A<>B.

I can use the IBus panel (handy, using shortcut) or the settings (**System Settings > Hardware: Input Devices > Keyboard > Advanced > Switching to another layout**).

The problem is that the IBus does not allow me to choose one specific keyboard (US layout with European letters), so when I switch using IBus from A to keyboard B, I cannot come back to keyboard A, unless I go to settings and set it manually.

How could I correct this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are on 20.04 (or lower), this was improved in 20.10.

On 20.04 you can open `/usr/share/ibus/component/simple.xml` for editing and add the layout(s) you need. [This comment](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/issues/2153#issuecomment-553827474) shows an example of what it may look like.